# Como puedo agregar encabezados y pie de paginas en tinyMCE versión 6?

Tags: headers, tinymce, footer

Estoy trabajando con el plugin TinyMCE versión 6 embebido en un BPMS, este funciona correctamente, pero necesito agregar encabezado y pie de pagina en cada página generada en un documento de múltiples páginas. Trabajamos con el plugin externo de sirap-group, https://github.com/sirap-group/tinymce-plugin-headersfooters. No se logra unificar el documento al genera tres Texta[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]rea donde la superior queda fija (encabezado) y el parte inferior (pie de pagina), el content lleva el documento al tratar de generar el documento salen en forma independiente y no se unifica que se requiere.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.